# Oracle Merge not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a master table containing millions of records. Each day, we take a dump file from another system (containing roughly 7 days of data) and run it against the master file using a MERGE statement. MATCHes are supposed to update the master table, NOT MATCHED is supposed to insert a new row into our table.

About a month back, we realized that it was not handling the situation in which one of the key fields could be null - always resulting in a nonmatch.  We edited the matching logic like this:

```
    on nvl(src.field1,'xxxxxxx') = nvl(tgt.field1,'xxxxxxx') and
       nvl(src.field2,'xxxxxxx') = nvl(tgt.field2,'xxxxxxx') and
      nvl(src.field3,'xxxxxxx') = nvl(tgt.field3,'xxxxxxx')
```

Only the second and third fields actually contain nulls as far as we've seen, but we put the logic on all 3 just to be sure.

The problem is, this has not fixed the problem - and we've found that it's actually creating not just multiple rows for the same combination of keys, but completely duplicate entries - far in excess of what we'd expect for a twice-a-day compare with a 7-day rolling window in the update file (7 x 2 means I wouldn't be surprised to see 14 duplicate records).

The primary issue, though, is that it seems to be not-matching even though we've fixed the logic for null values. We cannot replicate this with a small data set, nor with a simplified made-up data set (see below).

Is it possible that the sheer volume of data (> 100M rows in the master table, 600K in the feeder), or the existing duplicates, are somehow tripping the update process and causing this?

A very simplified example is below:

Set up tables (do for TEST_SOURCE and TEST_TARGET)

```
create table test_source ( -- and same for test_target
    key1        varchar(20) not null,
    key2        varchar(20),
    key3        varchar(30),
    datefield   date,
    data1       varchar(20),
    data2       varchar(20),
    data3       varchar(20)
    );
```

Set up test data

```
insert into test_target 
select 'A1' as key1,'B1' as key2,'C1' as key3, '01-Aug-1901' as datefield,'D1' as data1, 'E1' as data2, 'F1' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A2' as key1,'B2' as key2,'C2' as key3, '01-Aug-1901' as datefield,'D2' as data1, 'E2' as data2, 'F2' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A3' as key1,null as key2,'C3' as key3, '01-Aug-1903' as datefield,'D3' as data1, 'E3' as data2, 'F3' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A4' as key1,'B4' as key2,null as key3, '01-Aug-1904' as datefield,'D4' as data1, 'E4' as data2, 'F4' as data3 from dual;

insert into test_source 
select 'A1' as key1,'B1' as key2,'C1' as key3, '01-Sep-1901' as datefield,'D1x' as data1, 'E1x' as data2, 'F1x' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A2' as key1,'B2' as key2,'C2' as key3, '01-Sep-1901' as datefield,'D2x' as data1, 'E2x' as data2, 'F2x' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A3' as key1,null as key2,'C3' as key3, '01-Sep-1903' as datefield,'D3x' as data1, 'E3x' as data2, 'F3x' as data3 from dual
union all select 'A4' as key1,'B4' as key2,null as key3, '01-Sep-1904' as datefield,'D4x' as data1, 'E4x' as data2, 'F4x' as data3 from dual;
```

Target data, that needs to be updated

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 DATEFIELD DATA1 DATA2 DATA3     
"A1" "B1" "C1" 8/1/1901  "D1"  "E1"  "F1" 
"A2" "B2" "C2" 8/1/1901  "D2"  "E2"  "F2" 
"A3" null "C3" 8/1/1903  "D3"  "E3"  "F3" 
"A4" "B4" null 8/1/1904  "D4"  "E4"  "F4"
```

Source data, to use to do the update

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 DATEFIELD DATA1 DATA2 DATA3    
"A1" "B1" "C1" 9/1/1901  "D1x" "E1x" "F1x"    
"A2" "B2" "C2" 9/1/1901  "D2x" "E2x" "F2x"    
"A3" null "C3" 9/1/1903  "D5x" "E3x" "F3x"    
"A4" "B4" null 9/1/1904  "D4x" "E4x" "F4x"
```

MERGE logic (with corrected compares):

```
merge into test_target tgt
using (select key1, key2, key3, datefield, data1, data2, data3 from test_source) src 
on (nvl(src.key1,'xxxxx') = nvl(tgt.key1,'xxxxxx') 
    and nvl(src.key2,'xxxxxx') = nvl(tgt.key2,'xxxxxx') 
    and nvl(src.key3,'xxxxxx') = nvl(tgt.key3,'xxxxxx'))
when matched then update set tgt.data1 = src.data1, tgt.data2 = src.data2, tgt.data3 = src.data3, tgt.datefield = src.datefield 
when not matched then insert (key1, key2, key3, datefield, data1, data2, data3) 
    values (src.key1, src.key2, src.key3, src.datefield, src.data1, src.data2, src.data3);
```

After merge, with null-handling bug unfixed, after running several times; rows with no nulls worked. The current logic in production and development environments is behaving this way despite the fix but I cannot replicate the bug.

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 DATEFIELD DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 
"A1" "B1" "C1" 9/1/1901 "D1x"  "E1x" "F1x"  
"A2" "B2" "C2" 9/1/1901 "D2x"  "E2x" "F2x"  
"A3" null "C3" 8/1/1903 "D3"   "E3"  "F3" 
"A3" null "C3" 9/1/1903 "D3x"  "E3x" "F3x"  
"A3" null "C3" 9/1/1903 "D3x"  "E3x" "F3x"  
"A3" null "C3" 9/1/1903 "D3x"  "E3x" "F3x"  
"A4" "B4" null 8/1/1904 "D4"   "E4"  "F4" 
"A4" "B4" null 9/1/1904 "D4x"  "E4x" "F4x" 
"A4" "B4" null 9/1/1904 "D4x"  "E4x" "F4x" 
"A4" "B4" null 9/1/1904 "D4x"  "E4x" "F4x"
```

After merge, with bug fixed (behaving as expected).

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 DATEFIELD DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 
"A1" "B1" "C1" 9/1/1901 "D1x" "E1x" "F1x" 
"A2" "B2" "C2" 9/1/1901 "D2x" "E2x" "F2x" 
"A3" null "C3" 9/1/1903 "D3x" "E3x" "F3x" 
"A4" "B4" null 9/1/1904 "D4x" "E4x" "F4x"
```

There must be something very simple that we're missing in trying to fix this, but we've been pounding our heads against a wall for weeks now.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose sample/simplified code that doesn't demonstrate the problem. Can you include at least your real `ON` clause? I would guess that you've either got column names confused, or the magic values (`'xxxxxxx'`) aren't actually quite the same. (I'm not a fan of that approach; I prefer explicit null checks... but it should work as long s the magic values are consistent and can't actually appear in the real data.) I'm sure you've checked that, but it's something we can't verify with re-typed dummy code.

Comment: an easier way to handle the nulls is: "decode(src.col, dest.col, 1,0) = 1" because decode treats nulls as being a 'match'